# php5 mail() function sendmail error

Tags: php, apache2, webserver, sendmail

I'm trying to use php's mail() function but keep getting an error.  I've installed sendmail via `sudo apt-get install sendmail`, edited my `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file adding the following text to these lines:

```
 sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
 sendmail_from = uslonsweb003.ALU@no-reply.com
```

I then restarted my webserver and used this command for test:

```
 :~$ php -r "mail('sadmicrowave@gmail.com', 'test subject', 'test body message');"
```

but I get the following error EVERYTIME!!!:

```
 sh: -t: not found
```

This is odd because I have tried the sendmail_path with -t and without -t but I keep getting the same error.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE! this is what my phpinfo() shows: (I added -t back but the command isn't working with or without it).

[image]

Another UPDATE -

I commented out the sendmail_path and sendmail_from lines to start from scratch expected the mail() function to complain that php doesn't know what it is but instead I get the EXACT same error as before (even without the two lines entirely!!). This leads me to believe that it doesn't have to do with the sendmail program or mail() function at all...

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but did you restart sendmail?

Comment: @tony - restarting the webserver entirely should do the same thing....right? - anyways - restarted the service manually and it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by utilising the SwiftMailer module where I can specify a mailserver to relay through.  I used my company mailserver as the server property and continued specifying the options as follows:

```
require_once('/var/www/global/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php');
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance( 'mailout.usa.mycompany.com', 25 );
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance( $transport );
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance( 'Suggestion Status Update' )
    ->setFrom( array( 'uslonsweb003@no-reply.com' => 'SuggestionBox' ) )
    ->setTo( array( $pEmail => $username ) )
    ->setBody( $body, 'text/html' )
    ;
$result = $mailer->send( $message );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but you might try `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`. It's set so on webhosting which I use. Otherwise, you might want to check if `phpinfo()` contains correct settings for `sendmail`.

Comment: I agree, it sound like whatever you did to set these new values isn't working and it is still using the defaults.

Comment: @Tony - see my original post for a screenshot of my phpinfo() output.

Comment: @sadmicrowave, you're missing the -i, also make sure that you do have indeed got sendmail in your /usr/sbin/, because mine was in /usr/bin; issue a "which sendmail" command to find out the exact path.

Answer (score 1):

I take the error to indicate that you are missing the information that -t would be looking for, 'To:' , 'CC:' , or 'BCC:'

Try adding some extra info to your mail command line and see if that works:

```
php -r "mail('sadmicrowave@gmail.com', 'test subject', 'test body message', 'To: Receiver <receiver@email.com>');"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following sections in your phpinfo() output to make sure you're editing the correct file:

- Loaded Configuration File
- Additional .ini files parsed

If the file you edited is not listed in one of those sections, the changes will have no effect.

Comment: the 'Loaded Configuration File' is `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` which I have also edited with the same content as in the cli/php.ini file...so the changes are obviously being captures. Also, refer to my screenshot in my OP to see that the changes are being captured...