# aspSmartMail object for PHP

Tags: php, email, object, smtp, mail-server

Is there a mail object like aspSmarMail that I can call from a PHP script specifying the 'server', 'senderaddress', 'recipient', etc. sub-properties?  For example in MS Visual Foxpro9 I can use this code:

```
 loIP = CREATEOBJECT( "aspSmartMail.SmartMail" )
 loIP.server = "mailout.my.domain.com"
 loIP.SenderName = "Emailer"
 loIP.SenderAddress = "madeupname@No-Reply.com"
 loIP.Recipients.Add( "sadmicrowave@gmail.com" ) 
 loIP.Subject = "Emailer Subject"
 loIP.ContentType = "text/html"
 loIP.Charset = "us-ascii"
 loIP.Body = "This is the body of the email"
 loIP.SendMail()
```

basically this will relay the generated email to the 'mailout.my.domain.com' mailserver and it will be sent out that way instead of having to install a SMTP MTA on my localhost.

Is there some syntax to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can call from a PHP script specifying the 'server', 'senderaddress', 'recipient', etc. sub-properties

While it's *kind* of possible to make PHP's built-in `mail` function communicate with an arbritary SMTP server, doing it sanely is difficult.  The best way to work with an SMTP server in PHP would be using a third-party mailing library.

[SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) comes highly recommended in these parts, but [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and PEAR's [Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected) package are also capable of communicating directly with an SMTP server.

Check out [SwiftMailer's documentation on sending via SMTP](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/smtp-transport) and [the way it assembles messages](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-quickref) for a quick howto.

Comment: SwiftMailer is exactly what I needed and it fixed my problem entirely, see this link for my full original post about this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869705/php5-mail-function-sendmail-error

Answer (score 1):

You should check our SwiftMailer, I recommend for all my customers on our hosting platform, it's very flexible:

> [SwiftMailer - Free Feature-rich PHP Mailer/](http://swiftmailer.org/)