# Email script reports success, but email does not appear in my inbox

Tags: php, html, email, forms

I created a form that is linked to a PHP page like this:

```
<form method="get" action="contact.php">
<p>Nome:</p> <input type="text" name="name" class="name" /><br>
<p>E-mail :</p> <input type="text" name="mail" class="mail" /><br>
<p>Website:</p> <input type="text" name="website" class="website" /><br>
Mensagem: <textarea name="message" class="message" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>        
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="submit" />
</form>
```

The PHP page:

```
<?php 
$field_name = $_GET['name'];
$field_email = $_GET['mail'];
$field_website = $_GET['website'];
$field_message = $_GET['message'];
$mail_to = '__munged__@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor ' . $field_name;
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
$headers = "From: $field_email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $field_email\r\n";
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');

    window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // Print a message
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to __munged__@template-help.com');
window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
}?>
```

I can't seem to figure out the problem.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding some onClick in submit and put the script data inside the function.

Comment: @Max — Umm. What? The script is being added to the page in response to the return value from PHP's `mail()` being true. Adding an onclick wouldn't help.

Comment: Is the script hosted on a Windows machine?

Comment: Yes , I have a windows machine but I'm testing all of this online , in a web host not in localhost

Comment: When declaring the $subject, you have unnecessary space between the string, the dot operator and the field_name variable.

Comment: Do you have access to the mail server? If yes, then check the log file there. Else ask your hosting company if they see something in the log file.

Comment: @Raffael Luthiger I already used this hosting company once and the contact form sent e-mails so the problem is not the hosting company  :s

Comment: @Sara Vieira: The problem is maybe not the hosting company but they have more information and can maybe help you.

Comment: I'll try to send them an e-mail

Answer (score 0):

If you had access to the web host I would say try to find the apache2.log file on an Ubuntu server this is located in `/var/log/` but I don't know where this would be for you.  Anyways, if you find this you can look at the last records in the log to see if apache is throwing an error during the execution of this command that is otherwise hidden from the user.  It sounds like there is probably a problem with the mail server.  Do you have one setup? are you using sendmail or some variant?

I recently had some related problems with sending mail, this might help you (but as I said before it is for linux)

[php5 mail() function sendmail error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869705/php5-mail-function-sendmail-error)

Comment: I already use this mail server and web hosting company before and it worked that's why i can't understand  :S

Answer (score 0):

Check the smtp server settings in `[mail function]` section of `php.ini` file. The mail server probably received the message successfully otherwise it would return an error. I would try to use different mail server.

Answer (score -1):

Its a simple method to do.

Remove Unused Spaces from subject.
Do Not use dynamic variable with subject like $field_name.

use php5 @mail function